# ggplot2 geom_mosaic with weight variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a mosaic plot with ggplot2.  I am using the `bladdercancer` data from the HSAUR3 package.  I am looking to show the relationship between tumorsize and number, but I am not sure how to weight it.  I know that the number in the sample with `tumorsizes<=3cm` is not the same as those with `tumorsize>3cm`.  How do I incorporate that into my mosaic plot?

Here is what I did without weighting it.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggmosaic")

ggplot(data = bladdercancer, family=poisson()) +
   geom_mosaic(aes(weight= 1 , x = product(tumorsize, number), 
   fill=factor(tumorsize)), na.rm=TRUE) +
   labs(x="Number of tumors", title='Number of tumors vs Tumorsize') + 
   guides(fill=guide_legend(title = "Tumor Size"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be late nevertheless I provide my suggestions since I am trying to do a similar thing. Below are two suggestions:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

first option:

```
bladdercancer %>%
group_by(tumorsize, number) %>%
# get frequencies/counts for each tumor size and for each number
summarise(n.cases = n()) %>%
ggplot() +
geom_mosaic(aes(weight = n.cases, x = product(number), 
              fill = factor(n.cases)), offset = 0) +
guides(fill=guide_legend(title = "Tumor Size")) +
labs(x="Number of tumors", title='Number of tumors vs Tumorsize') + 
# remove background colour
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    # remove major and minor grids
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    # push title to the middle
    plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = .5))
```

[image: plot1]

where the categories within each column represent different counts for each tumor size e.g number 1 appears 15 times for `<=3cm` and 5 times for `>3cm`. I am however not able to partitions where the frequencies are the same, in this case number 3 and 4. Hence my option 2

second option:

```
ggplot(bladdercancer) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = number, fill = tumorsize), position = "dodge")
```

[image]